# Opening cursor files in a graphics editor?

Tags: cursor, image-viewers

I'm looking at `/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors`, and there is:

```
$ tree -s /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/
/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/
├── [       4096]  cursors
│   ├── [         14]  00008160000006810000408080010102 -> v_double_arrow
...
│   ├── [          5]  9d800788f1b08800ae810202380a0822 -> hand2
│   ├── [          8]  arrow -> left_ptr
│   ├── [      15776]  bd_double_arrow
│   ├── [      15776]  bottom_left_corner
│   ├── [      15776]  bottom_right_corner
│   ├── [      15776]  bottom_side
...
```

... a bunch of files without extension, that GIMP cannot open.

Is there an editor where these files can be opened - or at least a converter to something like `.png`? I can note that ImageMagick `display` also failed to open these files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cursor files uses `X11 cursor` type of files:

```
$ file /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/hand2
/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/hand2: X11 cursor
```

### GIMP plugin

You need a plugin to edit cursors files with GIMP called *"X11 Mouse Cursor (XMC) plug-in"* which you can find [here](https://github.com/bdonlan/gimp-plugin-registry/tree/master/xmc/gimp-xmc-plugin-2.0.6).

### The X tool

You can also create your own PNG images and transform them to cursors files using *"Xcursorgen"* which can be found in the `x11-apps` package.

### Third party

[Gursor Maker](http://gursormaker.sourceforge.net/) is a front end for xcursorgen.

References:

- http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2201
- http://mailman.cs.huji.ac.il/pipermail/linux-il/2009-April/001196.html
- http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_7486801_make-own-x11-cursors.html

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @Braiam - I want to open and look at the images (and potentially paste them), so `xcursorgen` wouldn't have helped me much; my experience with `GursorMaker` and `XMC` plugin are posted in the OP edit - GursorMaker seems too old even for 11.04; however XMC worked fine. Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 5):

[Xcursor Viewer](https://github.com/drizt/xcursor-viewer) can be used for preview cursor. It hasn't any editing features. Only viewing.[image]

Comment: This application is very small and lacks documentation, BUT, in order to compile it on fresh Linux Mint 19.3 (Tricia) - which is based on Ubuntu Bionic, I had to install qt5-default package, then type cmake . (note the dot), and then just simple make. Of course base tools for compilation should be installed too (binutils package, compilers, make, cmake, etc.). Then it works, but is unable to choose hidden directoris in directory list. This can be overcomed by using a symbolic link.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on github. Maybe I will improve this when I will have enough free time. Anyway I suprised that somebody uses this app.

Comment: @piotao you can simply right-click in the _Find Directory_ dialog's directory list and choose "Show hidden files"

Answer (score 2):

Pretty old thread, if somebody searching for this:

Gimp is now supports it natively. So just open and can export to xcm.

Answer (score 1):

copied from OP edit:

---

Found also [Gursor Maker - Cursor Editor for X11/GTK+](http://gursormaker.sourceforge.net/); got the CVS code from SourceForge - it still uses `Numeric` (the old name of `numpy`), so to run it, you'll have to do:

```
#from Numeric import *
from numpy import *
```

... in xcurio.py, curxp.py, gimp.py, colorfunc.py  - and comment the `#from xml.dom.ext.reader import Sax2` in lsproj.py. With that, I got it running 11.04:

[image: gursormaker]

... but cannot get any files to open? So I thought I should grep for paths, nothing much came up - and when I looked into `cursordefs.py`, I simply had to paste this:

```
CURSOR_ICON = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_xpm_data([
        "10 16 3 1",
        "       c None",
        ".      c #000000",
        "+      c #FFFFFF",
        "..        ",
        ".+.       ",
        ".++.      ",
        ".+++.     ",
        ".++++.    ",
        ".+++++.   ",
        ".++++++.  ",
        ".+++++++. ",
        ".++++++++.",
        ".+++++....",
        ".++.++.   ",
        ".+. .++.  ",
        "..  .++.  ",
        "     .++. ",
        "     .++. ",
        "      ..  "])
```

Heh `:)` In any case, doesn't look like it will be much usable on newer Ubuntus, unfortunately...

---

Just tested XMC plugin as well - on 11.04, has to be built from source (from the link in the accepted answer); the requirements on my system resolved to:

```
sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev libglib2.0-0-dbg libglib2.0-0-refdbg libglib2.0-cil-dev libgtk2.0-0-dbg libgtk2.0-cil-dev
```

... after that, the configure/make procedure in the `INSTALL` file works. Note that this plugin is a bit "sneaky":

[image: xmc]

... that is, you should use "All files" (as there are no extensions); cursor previews at first will *not* be rendered. Then open one cursor file; after it has been opened, then there *is* a preview in the File/Open dialog; but other than that, it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

There is also [xcur2png](http://cli-apps.org/content/show.php/?content=86010), which allows converting the image data of cursors to PNG and creates `.conf` files.

Only an inofficial 64bit .deb build [is available](https://launchpad.net/~s-lagui/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/2472534) but luckily the source is non-problematic to compile, just make sure libxcursor is installed.

This answer was found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241364/

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the GIMP plugin [Braiam](https://askubuntu.com/users/169736/braiam) mentioned and it seems to have disappeared. But by reading up on the [spec](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man3/Xcursor.3.xhtml) I was able to come up with a simple Makefile that will extract the first 24x24 pixel cursor from a typical file that has the first icon at an offset of 0x70:

```
ICONDIR ?= /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors
default: arrow.png
%.xxd: $(ICONDIR)/%
    xxd $< $@
%.bin: %.xxd
    sed -n '/^00000070:/,/^00000960:/p' $< | xxd -r -seek -0x70 > $@
%.png: %.bin
    convert -size 24x24 -depth 8 rgba:$< $@
```

It probably won't work for everybody. But it works on my Debian 10 netbook.