# Where is the Ubuntu cursor, in the source code?

Tags: cursor, source-code

I'm trying (and failing) to sift through [the source](http://archive.ubuntu.com/), attempting to find the image file(s) for the default cursor. **Does anyone know where this is?**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the cursor you have in graphic applications.

The cursor is not just an image; there is a whole "cursor theme" involved (it changes when selecting, writing text, etc.!). So the location of the files are theme-dependent.

In my Ubuntu Gnome the default cursor theme (you can check it with `gnome-tweak-tool`) is called Adwaita; searching for it with

```
 locate -i adwaita | grep -i cursor
```

points to `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors`. The files there are not simple graphic files, but X11 cursor files, whose manipulation is explained in this question: [Opening cursor files in a graphics editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375216/opening-cursor-files-in-a-graphics-editor)

`unity-tweak-tool` will [point you to the correct site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221942) if you have Unity.

You can also check this Q&A: [How to change mouse cursor and theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme).

In my standard gimp installation in Ubuntu I can simply open it; see:

```
% gimp left_ptr
```

[image: gimp opening a cursor]

as you can see, is a multi-layer image with the cursor for different size. If you just keep the biggest one, export to PNG, you have this:

[image: adwaita left_ptr]

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that didn't require _installing_ Ubuntu; I wanted them so I could have a free, open-source image to use as a thumbnail for what a cursor looks like.

Comment: So... why don't simply ask that? You can use the gimp plugin to read the icon files and then simply browse the [package `gnome-themes-standard`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-themes-standard) that contains them... no need to install anything --- well, the gimp plugin.

Comment: [this one](http://gimpstuff.org/content/show.php/X11+Mouse+Cursor+%28XMC%29+plug-in?content=94503)? It's for Debian/Redhat only

Comment: It's for GIMP. Now, it's a bit old and can have problem --- and Ubuntu is debian-based, so it should just work. See my update.

Comment: I mean it comes in `.deb` and `.rpm` files. How would I install this on Windows or OS X?

Comment: I know nothing about Windows and OS-X --- ask in the respective places. But you can just try; my GIMP opens the files just ok. (And by the way, installing a plugin in GIMP normally is just a matter of downloading the `.tar.gz` --- look down in the page you linked --- and decompress it in the right place.)

Comment: oh, thanks! I didn't see the `.tar.gz`s down there. I'll get back and say how it went!