# How can i preview the X11 cursor file?

Tags: 20.04, themes, cursor

Recently, I downloaded a pack of cursors. I just want to view the image of the cursors so i can change some of it. Can anybody help? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to build and install [**Xcursor Viewer**](https://github.com/drizt/xcursor-viewer).

I'm on Pop OS 20.10, but this shouldn't bee too different. I had to flop around trying to find the correct packages to install, and I bet they weren't all necessary; here's what I did (figured out some of the missing dependencies [here](https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs/issues/51)):

*Install likely dependencies:*

```
sudo apt install cmake qtattributionsscanner-qt5 qtchooser qt5-qmake-bin qt5-qmake qttools5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev cmake-qt-gui libqt5concurrent5 libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5opengl5-dev libqt5help5 libqt5opengl5 qdoc-qt5 qhelpgenerator-qt5 qt5-assistant qt5-default libqt5sensors5 libqt5webkit5 libmng2 libllvm10 libclang1-10 libglu1-mesa-dev libvulkan-dev
```

*Next, make a folder to put the source code*. Like ~/work/

```
cd ~/work && git clone https://github.com/drizt/xcursor-viewer.git
```

Then

```
cmake .
```

*If all goes well, it will say:*

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/YOURUSERNAME/work/git/xcursor-viewer
```

Then you can just tell it:

```
make
```

It will put the executable xcursor-viewer in the same directory.

*Once it's built,* to run it:

```
./xcursor-viewer
```

[image: xcursor-viewer open]

Click the button, and navigate to the folder with the cursors. The one that says `cursors`, inside the named directory.

[image: where to go to get xcursor-viewer to load the cursors]

Click `Open`, and you'll see all the cursors from that theme:

[image: xcursor-viewer showing cursors]

*To open the image files*

Now you know where they are, what they're named and what they look like. The cursor image files are "X11 cursor" format. GIMP and Glimpse can open these.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/375216/opening-cursor-files-in-a-graphics-editor